# UDF not updating value when Excel opened through code

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I've been trying the solutions I've found for similar questions, but it doesn't seem to be working to resolve my problem.

I have an Access database (Access 2016), which opens an Excel spreadsheet (Excel 2016) which does calculations.  I also have an Excel Add-In file that contains a ton of UDFs.  By default, I always have this Add-In installed in Excel and it's part of my profile boot script.  However, when Access opens Excel through code, it doesn't recognize the Add-In (whereas opening Excel myself does work).  So I've added code (per other forum suggestions) to uninstall and reinstall the Add-In after Excel opens.  See code below.

```
    Dim appExcel As Object
    Dim strpath As String

    strpath = "H:\Folder\Calculator.xlsm"

    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        appExcel.Workbooks.Open FileName:=strpath, UpdateLinks:=1, ReadOnly:=True

    Set wbk = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook
        appExcel.AddIns.Add FileName:="H:\Folder\AddInFile.xlam"

    If appExcel.AddIns("AddInFile").Installed = False Then
        appExcel.AddIns("AddInFile").Installed = True
    Else
        appExcel.AddIns("AddInFile").Installed = False
        appExcel.AddIns("AddInFile").Installed = True
    End If

    Set appExcel = Nothing
```

The only way to get my UDFs to work correctly requires me to go into every cell that contains one of these functions and manually force it to recalculate (F2-Enter).  Forcing a recalculation on the entire worksheet doesn't help.  It must be cell by cell.  The formulas "execute" but have incorrect results until I force them to recalculate.  Below is an example of one such function.

```
    Function Nx(Age, table, Interest)

    Dim l(0 To 121) As Double
    Dim D1(0 To 121) As Double
    Dim N1(0 To 121) As Double
    Dim v As Double
    Dim NAge As Double

    If Age > 120 Then
            NAge = 120
    Else
        NAge = Age
    End If

    l(0) = 9999.9999
    v = 1 / (1 + Interest)
    D1(0) = l(0)
    Nn = D1(0)
    x1 = Int(NAge)
    x2 = Int(NAge) + 1
    Fract = NAge - x1

    For j = 1 To 120
        l(j) = l(j - 1) * (1 - q(table, j - 1))
        D1(j) = l(j) * (v ^ j)
        Nn = Nn + D1(j)
    Next j

    N1(0) = Nn

    For j = 1 To 120
        N1(j) = N1(j - 1) - D1(j - 1)
    Next j

    Na = N1(x1) - D1(x1) * (11 / 24)
    Nb = N1(x2) - D1(x2) * (11 / 24)
    Nx = ((1 - Fract) * Na) + (Fract * Nb)

    End Function
```

This function works perfectly under any other circumstance. However, when you open Excel programmatically, it stops returning correct results. If you save the file and reopen it, everything updates correctly.

I can't seem to figure out a solution.  I previously asked this question, but the first response requested a sample of code and down-voted my question, and after a few weeks no one had tried answering me.  I really need to figure out a solution to this, so I figured I would try again with a fresh question.

Comment: Try to make it volatile. Use `Application.Volatile` in your UDF as first line.

Comment: Try loading the add-in **before** you open the desired workbook. You'll probably need to load a new blank workbook before you can add the add-in.

Comment: If you open it programmatically, use application.calculatefull on the excel.application object.

Comment: When Excel is opened via automation, *add-ins are not loaded*.  You will need to load them via your code.

Comment: BTW you don't need to uninstall and reinstall the addin:just open it as if it was an ordinary workbook in your access code that starts Excel.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: No to `Application.Volatile` - that is using a sledgehammer to open a peanut. The cost of using `Application.Volatile` is way too high for the benefits here. `Application.Calculate` on the Range(s) or `Application.CalculateFull` used judiciously when opening the sheet are more efficient. Based on experience converting code that used `Volatile` and `Calculate` excessively for a workbook that had something like 75,000 cells.

Comment: @AJD I'm aware of what volatile does. But as he said re-calculate did not work it was worth a try.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Forcing a calculation when opening is a lot different that forcing a calculation everytime something changes. That is worth noting for the learners here.

Comment: (Missed first edit cut-off) @Pᴇʜ: OP also noted that it works when opening Excel normally - so forcing a big cost for a small use case is not good value. Forcing a calculation when opening is a lot different that forcing a calculation everytime something changes. That is worth noting for the learners here. Also why a `Range.Calculate` is worth considering. The real problem here is that an Access application is relying on an Excel add-in to perform some work.

Comment: `Option Explicit`! `q` is not declared. And you haven't declared types on your parameters. I have just looked at the code, and it is spaghetti and inefficient. You don't really use half the code in there.

Comment: I also have been hesitant to use volatile in the code because this Add-in affects thousands of spreadsheets, many of which are incredibly large.  Also, the mention of Option Explicit.  I have been planning on cleaning the code up for some time, but haven't gotten around to it.  Most of this wasn't programmed by me but I now maintain it.  It drives me insane to see so many undeclared variables in use and frivolous code, but there are hundreds of functions just like this and I haven't found the time.
I'll update again once I've had time to try some of these ideas.

Comment: So CalculateFull seems to have solved the problem.  I previously tried using the calculate buttons in the ribbon to force a recalculation of the worksheet, but it didn't do anything.  Adding this when opening the workbook seems to have solved the problem.  Thank you for all of your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put,

```
application.volatile
```

as the first line of your function's code. Alternately or in concert, use,

```
application.calculatefull
```

on the excel.application object.